# how to using Custom Master Key to generate plain key and encrypt key with java

Tags: java, security, encryption, amazon-kms

I am reading the amazon key management system [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/create-keys.html). I have tried to implement the encrypt and decrypt workflow by myself. I am using this java code to generate a custom master key like this:

```
  private static SecretKey generateMasterKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyGenerator keyGen = null;

    keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); 
    
    keyGen.init(256); // 256 bit key
    SecretKey masterKey = keyGen.generateKey();
    return masterKey;
  }
```

The next step is to use the [custom master key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#customer-cmk) to generate 2 types of key, the encrypt key and unencrypt key (I do not know how to explain the key name the right way, the key could encrypt the password for the next step). I want to use the unencrypt key to encrypt the password and store the password encrypt content and encrypt text in database. How to generate the encrypt key and unencrypt key from the custom master key? The two keys like the image:

[image]

Comment: Question is very unclear. It seems like you want to use a symmetric key to generate (?) an asymmetric keypair? (Btw, the inverse of "encrypt" is "decrypt".)

Comment: I have add some explain but I still did not know what is the right words to explain the two key name generate by custom master key. I called it plaintext data key and encrypt data key. the plaintext data key to encrypt password and encrypt data key to decrypt the password in the future.@RobbyCornelissen

Comment: That diagram shows something fundamentally different from the text of your question. The `plaintext data key` is the symmetric key that you will actually use to encrypt and decrypt the data. The `encrypted data key` is that original key 'wrapped' under the KMS key. You can (and typically will) safely store this encrypted data key with the ciphertext. To decrypt a ciphertext you take the EDK, unwrap it using the KMS key to obtain the original data key - and use that to decrypt the data.

Comment: There are two KMS primitives that let you "generate the encrypt key": either you (cryptographically securely, of course) generate it yourself and then `encrypt` it with the master key and the context to obtain the EDK; or you have KMS do the work for you - the other primitive generates a PDK for you, encrypts it and returns to you this random PDK and the PDK encrypted (with the context) as the EDK.

Comment: If what you are looking to do is encrypt and decrypt data using key(s) stored in KMS, don't roll your own. Use the AWS Encryption SDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java.html This does the work for you and provides additional best-practice features you'd be unlikely to add on your own, like key derivation and commitment and (optional) signing.